# Prove that the limit converges.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I would like some help with the following proof.

Suppose 
$(a_n)$ is a sequence of positive real numbers and $L= \lim \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$. If $0 \le L < 1$, and $L< p< 1$, then $((n^p) a_n)$ converges to $0$.

We have already proven the ratio test in class,  so I know that $(a_n)$ converges to $0$ by supposition.

Comment: Edited. Thanks.

Comment: Re the title, note that a *limit* does not *converge*, it exists or it does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

First recall the contrapositive form of the $n$th term test for divergence:

$$\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} n^pa_n \space \text{converges} \implies \lim \limits_{n\to \infty} n^pa_n = 0.$$

So it will suffice to show that the infinite series on the left converges, which you can do with the ratio test.

$\lim \limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{(n+1)^pa_{n+1}}{n^pa_n} = (\lim \limits_{n\to \infty} (\frac{n+1}{n})^p)\cdot(\lim \limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}) = 1 \cdot L = L <1$, by suppositions about $a_n$, hence the series converges absolutely, hence the limit of the terms of the series converges to $0$.